# A class with no contructor (Python)

Tags: python

Given that I need to operate a machine, I need a
VendingMachine class:

Property is a stock(list) that stores Food items.

Methods:

Constructor takes in no arguments.
get_stock_names(): returns a list of strings that represents the names of
all food items in the stock.
load(food): adds the Food object to stock

and others,

```
#predefined
class Food(object):
    def __init__(self, name, nutrition, good_until):
        self.name = name
        self.nutrition = nutrition
        self.good_until = good_until
        self.age = 0
    def get_name(self):
        return str(self.name)
    def get_age(self):
        return self.age
    def get_nutrition(self):
        if self.age <= self.good_until:
            return self.nutrition
        else:
            return 0
    def ripen(self, days):
        self.age = self.age + days
        return self.age
    def is_spoiled(self):
        return self.good_until < self.age

#my code below

class VendingMachine:
    def __init__(self):
    Property = Food.get_name   #no clue how to make a Property
    self.load = Food.load       #same here
    def get_stock_names(self, Property):
        lst = []
        for i in Food:
            i = str(i)
            lst.append(i)
        return lst
    def has_stock(self, name):
        return name in Property
    def load(self, food):
        Property.append(food)
        return Property
    def sell(self, name):
        if name in Property:
            Property.remove(name)
            return name
        else:
            return None
```

What I get is
AttributeError: 'VendingMachine' object has no attribute 'load' (a variable)

Comment: Due to the formatting, it's hard to tell what your intended indentation was - I assume that it is right, in which case, your issue is that you are defining your functions inside the constructor, not the class. This means they are local to the constructor.

Comment: make sure load attribute is defined in Food class and VendingMachine inherit from Food class.

Comment: @sjcipher Why should VendingMachine inherit from Food? That doesn't make sense. Admittedly, a lot of the given code doesn't make much sense, but I'm pretty sure that wasn't the intention.

Comment: But surely VendingMachine HAS Food, not IS Food?

Comment: The two lines really confusing me in this are the first two in the VendingMachine constructor - the OP says `Property` is a list, but assigns it a function (which doesn't even return a list if it was an accident not to call it), and then overrides what the `load` function might be by assigning a non-existent value.

Comment: What are you trying to do actually ?

Comment: @Lattyware then he should define as class method, m just saying from the way how he is trying to access it.

Comment: @Lattyware that's actually the portion I'm unsure about. Since the question is asking to use no arguments I don't know where to start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you've misunderstood the line of your instructions telling you about the `stock` property. I suspect it is just telling you to make an instance variable named `self.stock` which holds a list of `Food` instances. Since the constructor takes no arguments, it presumably starts empty. Using the term "property" seems like a red herring, since `property` has a specific meaning in Python (a wrapper around a method to make it look like an attribute), which doesn't make much sense in this situation.

Anyway, here's what I think you want your constructor to look like:

```
def VendingMachine(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.stock = [] # initially empty
```

Your later methods can inspect or manipulate `self.stock` as necessary.